# How to pass variable value from one LWC component to another without parent child relationship

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-message-service

**JS of ProductList Component**

```js
import { LightningElement, api, track, wire } from "lwc";
import getProducts from '@salesforce/apex/reviewsController.getProducts';
// import productDetails from '@salesforce/apex/reviewsController.productDetails';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';
export default class ProductsList extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    @wire(getProducts) wiredgetProducts;
    @track clickedButtonLabel;

    //call method start
    @api searchKey = '';
    // @wire(productDetails, { searchKey: '$searchKey' })
    // wiredproductDetails;
    handleClick(event) {
        this.clickedButtonLabel = event.target.label;
    }
    navigateToProdDetailPage(event) {
        this.searchKey = event.target.dataset.id;
        console.log('this.searchKey', this.searchKey);

        // Navigate to a URL
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'comm__namedPage',
            attributes: {
                name: 'productdetailspage__c',
                actionName: 'view',
            }
        },
            // true // Replaces the current page in your browser history with the URL
        );
    }
}
```

**JS of Product Detail**

```js
import { LightningElement, api, track, wire } from "lwc";
import productDetails from '@salesforce/apex/reviewsController.productDetails';
export default class ProductDetails extends LightningElement {
    @wire(productDetails, { searchKey: '$searchKey' })
    wiredproductDetails;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to pass data between two unrelated component

Condition 1 :
If both component are in same lightning app. then you can use **Expose Event in LWC**

> https://www.forcetrails.com/2021/08/publish-lwc-events-to-lightning-app-builder.html

**Note:** you can use pubsub as well

Condition 2:
If both component are in different lightning app. the you can use **LMS**

Comment: It is best to use Salesforce terminology - here "dynamic interactions" - and to link to the [official documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.dynamic_interactions_overview.htm&type=5).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass data between two unrelated component you can use LMS(Lightning message Service) to achieve it.

Attaching a link to the standard document from where you can get much better understanding of [LMS](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-message-service).

Comment: IMHO this is more of a comment than an answer. The answer should provide more about the rationale, give an example against the provided code if that's not too complex to do and/or quote and link to the official Salesforce documentation.